# Number field in Custom Metadata returning inconsistent formatting when queried

Tags: metadata, number

I don't understand how this is possible?

I have a simple custom metadata object with a number field (7,0) called Portal Id.
The first record has a value of 20 in that field.

When I run this query I get different results in different orgs, but they are all on Winter 24:

```
Forms_and_Audience_Data__mdt [] cmd = [select label, Portal_Id__c
FROM Forms_and_Audience_Data__mdt];

System.debug(cmd[0].Portal_Id__c);
```

In one sandbox, this apex returns this value when I run a debug log:
**20**

But in Prod (which is also still on Winter 24), and another sandbox I get
**20.0**

Where's that trailing zero coming from in Prod?

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why does this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex has a lot of internal "magic" that goes on, relative to some other languages.

For example, consider the following code:

```
Decimal a = 20;
Decimal b = 20.0;
System.debug(a); // 20
System.debug(b); // 20.0
```

This appears to be a problem with `Object.toString`/`String.valueOf`. If you need a specific format, you can use functions like `intValue()` or `setScale(scale)` to force them into compliance.

```
Decimal a = 20;
a = a.setScale(1);
Decimal b = 20.0;
System.debug(a); // 20.0
System.debug(b); // 20.0
```

As to why there are differences, it's impossible for an outsider to tell. It may be related to how old the records are, the underlying database format, patch versions, or something else.

Comment: Yeah - that's what caught me out - in the initial sandbox, it was treating it like an integer - so my string manipulation worked fine. In Prod, it was reading like 20.0, so the LPAD failed